# Why plugin dynamic library can't find the symbol in the application?

Tags: c, dlopen

I have an application, which has been compiled several libraries into it through static link.

And this application will load a plugin through dlopen when it runs.

But it seems that the plugin can't resolve the symbol in the application, which I can find them through "nm".

So what can I do? Recompile the libraries into shared mode, and link them to the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the gcc flag `-rdynamic` when linking your application, which exports the symbols of the application for dynamic linkage with shared libraries.

From the gcc documentation:

> Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of dlopen or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.

This should eliminate your problem.

Comment: `-rdynamic` has important disadvantages as explained in other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The usual suggestion to add `-rdynamic` is too heavyweight in practice as it causes linker to export *all* functions in executable. This will slow down program startup (due to [increased time for relocation processing](https://lwn.net/Articles/341309/)) and, more importantly, will eventually make the interface between your application and plugins too wide so it would be hard to maintain in future (e.g. you won't be able to remove *any* function from your application in fear that it may be used by some unknown external plugin). Normally you should strive to expose a minimal and well-defined API for plugin authors.

I thus recommend to provide explicit exports file via `-Wl,--dynamic-list` when linking (see example usage in [Clang sources](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/4920d3228938c5ca6d6dd267da640e9ff65b6802/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp#L3180)).

Comment: Usually no prototypes exist for functions except those, that are part of the API in the public header files used by plugins which expose the API, so this is a non-issue in most cases.

Comment: Data? I have given you an argument (no exposal of prototypes of internal functions in public header files). If this is worked around in a hackish way, you probably could also work around non-exported functions in some way.

Comment: @Ctx OK, now I see what you mean. Still, if app author has taken time to define API for plugins (via dedicated header), he is likely responsible enough to provide export list as well (there's no good reason to risk plugin writers accessing app internals via unpublished but exported APIs). And if the header is not available, plugin authors will have to use internal headers and will freely access all functions.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your suggestion is good (+1). I just somehow dispute the "important disadvantages" you claim.